# What's the best way to change specific values in a cookie?

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I'm using SimpleCart JS, and I've been writing a coupon-code extension for it. Since SimpleCart uses a combination of the DOM and cookies to calculate price (I've got the DOM portion of this problem under control), I have to change a specific set of values in the cookie in order to actually alter the price of items that are in the cart *before* the coupon is entered.

Here's my question: How can I change the values of the `price=` variables in this cookie string?

Here's the cookie SimpleCart creates:

id=c4||quantity=1||name=XS%20Shirt%20%28Green%29||price=10++id=c5||quantity=1||name=XS%20Shirt%20%28Royal%20Blue%29||price=10++id=c6||quantity=1||name=%20Book||price=45.50

Currently, I'm sending this to a PHP script using POST and then exploding it into an array, but I can't figure out a way to isolate the prices so that I can modify them with a discount. The `++` that separates the prices from the id are throwing me off. I'm sure there's a way that Regex can do this, but all of my attempts at it have failed.

Here's the PHP script that I'm currently using to process the string:

```
$currentCookie = $_POST['currentCookie'];

$amount = $_POST['couponAmount'];   

$orderArray = explode('||',$currentCookie); 

print_r($orderArray);
```

Given the above string, this script returns this:

```
Array ( [0] => id=c4
[1] => quantity=1
[2] => name=XS%20Shirt%20%28Green%29
[3] => price=10++id=c5
[4] => quantity=1
[5] => name=XS%20Shirt%20%28Royal%20Blue%29
[6] => price=10++id=c6
[7] => quantity=1
[8] => name=%20Book
[9] => price=45.50 )
```

I need to modify the price values based on the `$amount` variable. The $_POST string looks like this:

```
?currentCookie=id=c4||quantity=1||name=XS%20Shirt%20%28Green%29||price=10++id=c5||quantity=1||name=XS%20Shirt%20%28Royal%20Blue%29||price=10++id=c6||quantity=1||name=%20Book||price=45.50&amount=10
```

The goal is to reduce all the prices by 10%, when `$amount = 10`. The math part looks like this:

```
$newPrice = $currentPrice - ($amount / 100 * (currentPrice));
```

### Thanks to the answerers. Here's what I wound up doing:

```
    $currentCookie = $_POST['currentCookie'];

function applyDiscount($price){

    $couponAmount = $_POST['couponAmount'];

    $newPrice = $price - ($couponAmount / 100 * ($price));

    return round($newPrice, 2);

}

$orderArray = explode('||',$currentCookie);

$output = array();

$pricePattern = '/(price=)([^\+]*)/';

foreach($orderArray as $item){

$currentPrice = preg_match($pricePattern, $item, $matches);

    $newPrice = preg_replace($pricePattern, applyDiscount($matches[2]), $item);

    if ($matches){
    array_push($output, 'price='.$newPrice);
    } else {
        array_push($output, $item);
    }

}

$output = implode('||', $output);

echo $output;
```

This takes the incoming string, splits it into an array, searches for and modifies the price (thanks to @stema), and then replaces the price variable.

Everything gets sewn back together and sent back to the page, where jQuery replaces the old cookie with the new one.

If anyone has a better or more elegant solution to this, I would really love to hear it. This feels clunky, but it works.

Comment: Please show the code you already have.

Comment: Updated to include code.

Comment: you need to add the name preceded with an @ (e.g. @Philippe Gerber) if you want to answer a comment otherwise the person will not be notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the price herewith

```
(price=)([^\+]*)
```

[See it online here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tor3)

I put the `price=` in group 1 and the value in group 2. The trick here is to match anything that is not a `+`. This will work when every price is really limited by a `+` or by the end of the string.

You can then replace with `$1NEWPRICE`.

Comment: This is great, thanks. How would I modify the value and then re-insert it into the string after finding it with Regex? I'm not very familiar with it, and your suggestion doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: @Carter, I am not a php programmer, so I am not able to give you detailed code for that. For regex search replace in php you have the function [`preg_replace`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), maybe you can do the calculation directly in the replacement option, I don't know. Otherwise you can do at first your search with `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` [See here](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) (you will find your result in $2), then do the calculation and as last step do the preg_replace with your result.

Comment: I learned a little more about preg_match, and it I got it working. I modified by question to include my now-working code. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Carter, you are welcome. It is possible that you answer your own question, so you should post your solution here as answer not within your question. It is also possible that you accept your own answer, but of course you can leave the question open for a while and wait for maybe better answers (or if you want you can accept my answer ;-))